# Does Firebase Realtime Database support auto data syncing between multiple databases?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is our use case:
We have way more than 200,000 clients need to connect to firebase realtime db. So we created multiple database with same data and load blance the connections.

Here is the problem:
If we update one database, we will have to initiate connection and udpate the rest of the database as well. I would like to check if there is a way to auto sync up data between multiple databases.

Docs I have went through:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding

Also I checked rules, and it seems that rules is not meant to be used to sync data.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain your use case? Syncing data in all shards may not be necessary tbh.

Comment: Hi @Dharmaraj, all our clients need to listen on the change of the same set of data over a period of time. This is why we cannot split the data and put into different databases.

For example, if we have 10 databases, at a certain point of time, we need to change the same set of data over 10 databases, and meanwhile all our clients need to listen on the change of the same data over 10 databases.

Comment: I get it but I was trying to understand your usecase and try if something sharding the db in a way that I explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68509022/how-to-shard-data-realtime-database-for-chat-app) could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is nothing built into Firebase to automatically synchronize data between multiple database instances. A common way to implement this when writing through a server-side process, is to simply write to each database in turn there.

If the data you want to write comes from a client-side SDK, I'd have the client write it to a staging area (just a temporary node in the database), and then use Cloud Functions to write the data the permanent location in all database instances.