# Will firebase be able to handle huge traffic?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, backend

So I have been coding a realtime chat app with flutter and firebase. Apparently there is a simultaneous concurrent connection limit of 200k on the RTDB, if my app reaches these limits, firebase suggests that I shard my database.

The problem with that is, that I cannot completely separate data from one database instance to another, as it's a realtime social media app, and one user should be able to access other user's information such as name, bio etc.

What I want to know is that, should I stick with firebase for this, or should I go with some other database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always access data from multiple shards on your app as long as you know which shard does the required data belong to. You can also use Firestore along with Realtime database to suit your needs.  Checkout the following answer for an example:

[How to shard data Realtime Database for chat app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68509022/13130697)

This stores all user profiles and basic information about the chats (including which shard is the conversation stored in) which makes it easier to query list of chats of a particular user(s) from Firestore and then read messages from realtime DB.

Comment: @Shreyash Shuka did this answer helped you? if it this way could you please upvote it or accept it to help the community. Thanks.

Comment: @Dharmaraj thanks a lot, this along with the reference was really helpful.