# Arrays or subcollections in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, data-structures, nosql

I have created a Firebase database with the following structure:
There are 3 main collections:
Users, Chats and another one which is not important for now.
I have initially planned to store  type documents in the Users collection, the type **User** is made of the properties:

```
uid         -> string
... (some others which are not important)
displayName -> string
chatsList   -> a SUBCOLLECTION of chat references, containing
    chat ID
    otherUserID -> the ID of the other user chatting with you
    
contacts  -> a SUBCOLLECTION of user references, containing
    user ID
    user displayName
```

type **Chat** is made like this (note that the chat is only between two users):

```
uid      -> string
user1    -> ID of one of the users in this chat
user2    -> ID of the other user
messages -> a SUBCOLLECTION of messages made of:
    uid       -> message ID
    senderID  -> user ID of who sent the message
    text      -> content of the message
    timestamp -> when was this message sent
```

So if I am a logged in user I know my id and if I want my chat with user id 123 I can query the collection "users/:myID/chatsList" and find the chat reference which satisfies: "otherUserID", "==", "123"
Then pick the related chat ID and find the actual chat in the Chats collection.

I am not sure but I understand that queries are shallow, so if I query for example the Chats collection I am not considering the subcollection Messages at all, so it should be faster?

Now the question is: do you think this is a good structure or is it better to not have those subcollections and use something like an array instead?

Answer (score 1):

> If I query for example the Chats collection I am not considering the subcollection Messages at all, so it should be faster?

Firestore queries are fast irrespective of you are fetching a document from a collection of 10 documents or 10 thousand. The only thing that can make your query slow is querying many documents at once as you will be downloading a lot of data.

> Is it better to not have those subcollections and use something like an array instead?

This totally depends on your use case. Firestore documents have a max size limit of `1 MB` so if there is no limit on how many messages, it's better to use a sub-collection.

Using a sub-collection can make it easier to:

1. Fetch/Update/Delete a single message by ID
2. Paginate the messages (when fetching a document, you get all the data in it)

If you need either of the features above, it might be better to use a sub-collection.

Do checkout [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/database) that sounds like a better option for chat applications in terms of pricing as well.

Also checkout: [How to shard data Realtime Database for chat app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68509022/how-to-shard-data-realtime-database-for-chat-app)